# Angular $scope.$watch on (for in... ) don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my code i have the following for watch changes in some variables

```
$scope.$watch('ns.namespacea.watchable_value', function(newVal, oldVal){
    //...
})

$scope.$watch('ns.namespaceb.watchable_value', function(newVal, oldVal){
    //...
})

$scope.$watch('ns.namespacec.watchable_value', function(newVal, oldVal){
    //...
})
```

the previous code work fine but I have many `namespaces` with a `watchable_value` and I wanna do

```
var namespaces = ['namespacea', 'namespaceb', 'namespacec'];

for (i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    var namespace = 'ns.' + namespaces[i] + '.watchable_value';
    console.log(namespace) //prints 'ns.namespacea.watchable_value', 'ns.namespaceb.watchable_value, ..
    $scope.$watch(namespace, function(newVal, oldVal){
        //...
    })
}
```

but the callback never is called

Comment: have you tried to console.log(namespace) just before the $scope.$watch?
And what do you mean by 'without success'? it could be an issue with the callback and not with the $watch

Comment: yes i tried console.log and showme the correct value, i've update the question for better understanding

Comment: the callback work fine I just do not want to write the same thing 7 times (for now)

Comment: I was mentionning the callback because it could be a closure issue as it's async: your callback is not aware of the namespace so the callback result could be wrong.
Have you tried to put an alert just at the beginning of the callback to be sure it isn't fired?

Comment: Are the namespaced values set correctly? ie: `ns['namespaceb']['watchable_value'] = someValue`

Comment: @SebastienC. after a while testing see only a namespace was watched N times and found i need add `do(namespace) ->` in my code for correct parse from coffeescript in `for .. in list`

Comment: that's the closure effect I was talking about

Comment: You can only watch scope variables. Just change var namespace to $scope.namespace =

Comment: @rkmax I just copied exact your code to the jsfiddle, it works great. http://jsfiddle.net/GbHZ7/

Answer (score 0):

When you use `for ... in`, you get keys, not values:

```
for (var namespace in myNamespaces) {
    $scope.$watch('ns.' + myNamespaces[namespace] + '.watchable_value', function(newVal, oldVal){
        //...
    })
}
```

Just index back into the array and you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I guess it's a callback issue, because this works fine:

```
$scope.ns= {namespacea: {value: 'testa'},
            namespaceb: {value: 'testb'},
            namespacec: {value: 'testc'}
           };
for (i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    var namespace = 'ns.' + namespaces[i] + '.value';
    console.log(namespace);
    $scope.$watch(namespace, function(newVal, oldVal){
        console.log(newVal);
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xdsn8/

So you just have to create a closure to make the callback aware of the namespace and it will work. Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xdsn8/1/

Answer (score 0):

when I wrap into closure like commet @SebastienC. works fine

```
namespaces = ['minuta', 'menu', 'plato'];

callback = function(i) {
  var name = 'ns.' + i + '.value';
  return $scope.$watch(name, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    // ...
  });
};

for (_i = 0, _len = namespaces.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  i = namespaces[_i];
  callback(i);
}
```